# Use of JSON_VALUE to return a JSON value containing \n as the newline character

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, json-value

Consider the following T-SQL in Microsoft SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE ('{"Value": "Normal Text 304\n1212\n1212\n121\na"}', '$.Value')
```

When this is executed, `\n` is converted to ASCII 10 (line feed) in the data, and it returns the following:

```
Normal Text 304 1212 1212 121 a
```

However, I need the JSON value to be returned as follows so the value can be injected into another JSON structure.

```
Normal Text 304\n1212\n1212\n121\na
```

For example:

```sql
SELECT
    ISJSON ('{"New Value": "' +  JSON_VALUE ('{"Value": "Normal Text 304\n1212\n1212\n121\na"}', '$.Value') +'"}')
```

This returns `0` as the JSON is not valid as it contains ASCII code `10`.

I would appreciate any advice on how to get a string value in JSON format from a JSON structure to paste into another JSON structure?

I could do a conversion from ASCII code `10` back to `\n` but that is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2017+, `STRING_ESCAPE()` is an option:

```
SELECT STRING_ESCAPE(
   JSON_VALUE('{"Value": "Normal Text 304\n1212\n1212\n121\na"}', '$.Value'), 
   'json'
) As EscapedJson
```

Result:

```
EscapedJson
-----------------------------------
Normal Text 304\n1212\n1212\n121\na
```

You may modify an existing JSON content using `JSON_MODIFY()`. In this situation, as is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments), `JSON_MODIFY()` *...escapes all special characters in the new value if the type of the value is NVARCHAR or VARCHAR*.

```
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
   '{"Key": "Normal Text"}',
   '$."New Value"',
   JSON_VALUE('{"Value": "Normal Text 304\n1212\n1212\n121\na"}', '$.Value')
) AS ModifiedJson
```

Result:

```
ModifiedJson
------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"Key": "Normal Text","New Value":"Normal Text 304\n1212\n1212\n121\na"}
```